# How to add tags in Json configuration of AWS emr

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr

How do i add --tags in json configuration of Amazon emr. I tried place it like below . But that doesn't work. This is my config.

```
 {
   "Name":"EMR",
   "LogUri":"------ ",
    "Tags": [ 
      { 
         "Key": "Name",
         "Value": "Bigdata"
      }
   ], 
   "Instances":{
      "InstanceGroups":[
         {
            "Name":"Master",
             ------
         },
         {
            "Name":"Slave",
            -----------
         },
         {
            "Name":"Task",
            ---------------
         }
      ],
      "TerminationProtected":false,
      "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps":true,
  ------------------------------------------
  ------------------------------------------   
   }
```

Comment: could you elaborate on what the error was?

Comment: @qfwfq There was no error. Just tag was not created in emr. I also tried giving tags inside properties. But that also doesn't work. May be i have given wrong syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags should come under **Properties**.
AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticmapreduce-cluster.html)

- YAML

```yaml
myEMRCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::EMR::Cluster'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: <name>
          Value: <value>
```

- JSON

```
"myEMRCluster": {
    "Type": "AWS::EMR::Cluster",
    "Properties": {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "<name>",
                "Value": "<value>"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have no idea but it's impossible to find it this on Airflow documentation. The format is exactly as you describe with Key and Value string.
I only have one comment .. on my case it's was wrong to add this under Properties. I will need to add on EmrCreateJobFlowOperator as part of job_flow_overrides parameter